Building a slider in html using css and javascript
Hello for a university project I need t rebuild a website, just the landing page, of a website. We only learned some basics in the course and I have trouble rebuilding the slider from the original website. I tried using chatgpt for help which was only helpful to a certain extend. The problem is that the slider continues to slide for about 5 more items which are empty.
I copied the information from chatgpt but the solutions to the problem never worked.
This is the javascript (which I don't know how it works at all because we didn't learn about it), is there anything that I can change so it works ?
 <script> 
    // Elemente auswählen
const prevButton = document.querySelector('.carousel-button.prev');
const nextButton = document.querySelector('.carousel-button.next');
const carouselContainer = document.querySelector('.carousel-container');
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.itemreisetipps');
let currentIndex = 0; // Aktueller Index des sichtbaren Items

// Funktion zum Berechnen der Breite des Karussells
function updateCarouselWidth() {
    const itemWidth = items[0].offsetWidth + parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(items[0]).marginRight); // Breite eines Items inkl. Abstand
    carouselContainer.style.width = `${itemWidth * items.length}px`; // Gesamtbreite des Containers
}

// Funktion zum Aktualisieren des Karussells
function updateCarousel() {
    const itemWidth = items[0].offsetWidth + parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(items[0]).marginRight); // Breite eines Items inkl. Abstand
    carouselContainer.style.transform = `translateX(-${currentIndex * itemWidth}px)`;
}

// Vorheriger Button
prevButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (currentIndex > 0) {
        currentIndex--;
    } else {
        currentIndex = items.length - 1; // Schleife zurück zum letzten Item
    }
    updateCarousel();
});

// Nächster Button
nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (currentIndex < items.length - 1) {
        currentIndex++;
    } else {
        currentIndex = 0; // Schleife zurück zum ersten Item
    }
    updateCarousel();
});

// Beim Laden der Seite und bei Fenstergrößenänderung die Breite des Karussells anpassen
window.addEventListener('load', updateCarouselWidth);
window.addEventListener('resize', updateCarouselWidth);

    </script>


A simple example of image slider.


var slidecnt=0;

function slideleft(obj){
var els=document.getElementsByClassName("slideimagebox");
var btns=document.getElementsByClassName("slidebtn");
if(slidecnt<els.length-1){btns[1].style.opacity="1";els[0].style.marginLeft=(-1*els[0].offsetWidth*(++slidecnt))+"px";}
if(slidecnt>=els.length-1){obj.style.opacity="0";}
}

function slideright(obj){
var els=document.getElementsByClassName("slideimagebox");
var btns=document.getElementsByClassName("slidebtn");
if(slidecnt>0){btns[0].style.opacity="1";els[0].style.marginLeft=(-1*els[0].offsetWidth*(--slidecnt))+"px";}
if(slidecnt<=0){obj.style.opacity="0";}
}

function adjustslide(perwid){
var btns=document.getElementsByClassName("slidebtn");
btns[1].style.opacity="0";
var inw = window.innerWidth;
var imgels=document.getElementsByClassName("slideimage");
var slidehold=document.getElementById("slideholderid");
slidehold.style.width=(perwid*inw/100)+"px";
slidehold.style.height=(perwid*inw/100)+"px";
for(var a=0;a<imgels.length;a++){
imgels[a].style.width=slidehold.offsetWidth+"px";
imgels[a].style.height=slidehold.offsetHeight+"px";
}
}

function startonload(){
adjustslide(40);
}
.slideimage{width:400px;height:400px;}
.slideimagebox{display:inline-flex;transition:0.8s;}
.slidebtn{transition:0.8s;font-size:18px;cursor:pointer;border:2px solid #FF0000;z-index:1002;position:relative;border-radius:50%;background-color:white;width:20px;height:20px;}
<body onload="startonload();">

<table><tr>

<td><div align="center" class="slidebtn" style="left:34px;" onclick="slideleft(this);">&lt;</div></td>

<td><div id="slideholderid" style="overflow:hidden;width:200px;height:200px;clear:both;display:inline-flex;">

<div class="slideimagebox"><img src="3.jpg" class="slideimage"/></div>
<div class="slideimagebox"><img src="4.jpg" class="slideimage"/></div>
<div class="slideimagebox"><img src="5.jpg" class="slideimage"/></div>
<div class="slideimagebox"><img src="4.jpg" class="slideimage"/></div>

</div></td>

<td><div align="center" class="slidebtn" style="right:35px;" onclick="slideright(this);">&gt;</div></td>



</tr></table>

<div>use function adjustslide(width percentage); in body onload</div>

</body>



